# jsgrid returns blank line after update

Tags: jsgrid

After giving an update via ajax in jsgrid the line returns blank

```js
controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {
        var data = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/app/Play/",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
            data.resolve(response);
        });
        return data.promise();
    },
    updateItem: function(item) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/app/Play/change.php",
            data: item,
        });
    },
}
```

In the return of the url update: `/app/Play/change.php`

I return the updated record data in a normal json, same as the initial json used in the load

Comment: Can you make some working fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```js
controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {
        var data = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/app/Jogos/app/",
            data: filter, // <--Insert line, this is a problem
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response) {
            data.resolve(response);
        });
        return data.promise();
    },
    updateItem: function(item) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/app/Jogos/app/change.php",
            data: item
        });
    },
},
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation. Please explain how you resolved issue?

Comment: For me the problem was that the JSON response was pascalCase instead of CamelCase (.NET Core Problem..). I then switched the default settings to camelCase